# How to convert a lead owned by queue?

Tags: apex, lead-conversion, queue, required-field, owner

I am getting an issue:

> REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Converted objects can only be owned by users. If the lead is not owned by a user, you must specify a user for the Owner field.: [OwnerId] while converting a lead by database.leadconvert().

Anyway, I need to convert this lead. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When converting leads owned by a queue, the owner must be specified. This is because accounts and contacts cannot be owned by a queue. Even if you are specifying an existing account or contact, you must still specify an owner.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_convertlead.htm

So, the answer is to set the `OwnerId` on your `LeadConvert` object using the `setOwnerId(ownerId)` method.

Here's the documentation for `LeadConvert` class - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm

If you need additional help, please provide your code in your question above.